# How significant is the difference between Western DIgital Red and Purple for CCTV footage?

Tags: hard-disk

I would like to have 6TB of RAID1 for CCTV footage. Instead of buying 2 6TB WD Purple drives + RAID enclosure, I was wondering if I can just get a MyBook Duo (which has 2 WD Red drives in it).

Will the WD Red hard drives die significantly faster if I use them for storing CCTV footage 24/7?
Is it worth spending the extra money+time to get 2 WD Purples + a RAID enclosure?

Comment: The difference between Western Digital hard drives is in firmware design, not in durability.  WD Purple is optimized for simultaneous sequential writes; WD Red is optimized for random read and write access.